# Lock a particular app with passcode or TouchID

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to lock a particular app like facebook, whatsapp etc with Passcode or TouchID, so unauthorized users can't access the apps that I want to protect.

I didn't find any way on web, not sure is it possible to lock any particular app?

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/abpadlockscreen

Answer (score 1):

At the start of the App implement a login screen, for touchID (touchID is iOS8+) you can use this code:

```
LAContext *context = [[LAContext alloc] init];
context.localizedFallbackTitle = @"Enter PIN";
[context evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics localizedReason:@"PIN Authentication" reply:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
   if (success)
   {
      //success, let's get started!
   }
   else if (error.code == LAErrorUserCancel)
   {
     NSLog(@"Authentication failed: %@", @"TouchID authentication cancelled");               
   }
   else if (error.code == LAErrorAuthenticationFailed) 
   {
      NSLog(@"Authentication failed: %@", @"TouchID authentication failed");
   }
   else if (error.code == LAErrorUserFallback) 
   {
      NSLog(@"Authentication failed: %@", @"TouchID authentication pin authentification fallback selected");
   }
   else if (error.code == LAErrorSystemCancel) 
   {
      NSLog(@"Authentication failed: %@", @"Touch authentication was canceled by system (e.g. another application went to foreground).");                
   }
   else if (error.code == LAErrorPasscodeNotSet) 
   {
      NSLog(@"Authentication failed: %@", @"Touch authentication could not start, because passcode is not set on the device.");
   }
   else if (error.code == LAErrorTouchIDNotAvailable) 
   {
      NSLog(@"Authentication failed: %@", @"Touch authentication could not start, because Touch ID is not available on the device.");
   }
   else if (error.code == LAErrorTouchIDNotEnrolled) 
   {
      NSLog(@"Authentication failed: %@", @"Touch authentication could not start, because Touch ID has no enrolled fingers.");
   }
   else 
   {
      NSLog(@"Authentication failed: %@", @"Touch ID has not been setup or system has cancelled");                
   }
}];
```

Comment: I didn't mean to use TouchID or Passcode to secure my own application.

Comment: @IrfanGul In iOS, apps run in a sandbox, you have very limited access to some resources of other apps and the iOS operating system, but you cannot change the way they behave. In other words, you cannot influence the starting mechanism of other apps. At least not with the official operating system, it may be possible with a jailbroken version..